# Javascript function that scans input and returns a link

Tags: javascript, sql

Hello I'm starting a little project while away from school during the summer and I thought I would ask the great minds of Stackoverflow for some advice on where to start.

I'm creating an online wiki for a simple iphone card game I'm working on to gain coding experience.  I have a submit problems page on my site that testers can submit bugs they've found in the game. I want to create a javascript query that scans the user submitted ticket for keywords. My keywords are on an SQL database.  This javascript query will scan the submitted ticket for a match, then provide back to me a link to my wiki where I might find a solution to their problem.  I could then use this link and send it to the player.  If it doesn't find a link, I would know I need to create a write up for this issue.

So in a nutshell...

- User submits a ticket to me
- This javascript code scans the ticket for matching keywords from my SQL keywords database.
- The javascript code then provides links to the matching keywords.  (each keyword has a link associated with it)

I'm looking for ideas where to start creating a JS function that does this.  I'm thinking...

- Create keyword SQL database
- Create js function that scans an inputted text field and places each matched keyword into an array
- After completing the scan the JS function then looks at each keyword in the array and provides a link to the correct wiki page (maybe hardcoded URLs associated with keywords)

Does this sound like the right way to approach creating a solution for this function?  Thanks for any help guys, this site is amazing for help and advice.

Comment: this sounds a little bigger than just one function!

Comment: This site might be amazing for help and advice but it's not a code-me-something-for-free-website. Besides:that is more likely a server side task than JavaScript or client side

Comment: This is a rather uncalled for comment.  I didn't ask for someone to code this for, I enjoy coding myself.  I'm asking for advice on how to approach this task.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.